# Optimal access of NUMBER(14) column via ODBC instant client 32-bit driver

Tags: c++, odbc

I am working on an application written in C++ that uses the 32-bit Instant Client drivers to access an Oracle database. The application uses the Record Field Exchange (RFX) methods to update the columns in the database tables. The database schema cannot be modified.

The C++ code was originally written to handle OID values as doubles because the OID column in the database is NUMBER(14), so a regular int won't be big enough. However, this leads to the database occasionally selecting a bad execution plan where it takes the OID values sent from the application and uses the to_binary_double function on them, rather than converting them to BIGINT. If this happens, the database does not do an index search over the data and instead does a full table scan.

We tried switching the OIDs to be type __int64 in the application, but there was an issue with the ODBC driver not supporting the BigInt type (or long long in C++). Similarly, when we tried to make the OIDs into longs, the database or the driver gave an error that the values sent to the database were too big for the column.

Working with the OIDs as Strings in C++ will work, but the database will never use the optimal index search because it has to convert the String to an integer before it can do any data retrieval. Because of this, we're just better off using the doubles we already have.

Does anyone have an idea of what we can do next? It is not the end of the world if we have to keep using doubles as before, but we were hoping to eliminate the chance for the database to run slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually went with the "Convert all the OIDs to Strings in the C++ code" option. It turns out the database was still able to run an indexed search after converting the OIDs from Strings to integers. It would have been better if we switched ODBC driver to one that could handle BigInt, but that wasn't really an option for us so this will suffice.